# Issue in implementing a cloth simulation using verlet integration

Tags: computational-physics, software

I am trying to implement a cloth simulation in c++ using verlet integration and I'm getting some odd issues that I can't seem to explain, the points in the cloth seem to fly around and have weird behavior.

to investigate I tried to simply place 2 dots next to each other horizontally with a single constraint and to pin one of the points, this should give the effect of the second point falling until both points are vertical.

what I am seeing is the unpinned point is swinging around the first one faster and faster, the odd thing is that if I am moving the simulation `step by step` using the keyboard I get the desired result what makes me think it might be a timestamp issue..

here is the code, I used glm for calculations and SFML for display.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using vec3 = glm::vec3;

#define NUM_OF_ITERATIONS 1
#define TIMESTAMP 0.01f
#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define drag 0.001f

#define logInfo(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl;
#define logDebug(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl;
#define logWarning(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl;
#define logError(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl;

struct Particle
{
    vec3 m_currentPos;
    vec3 m_previousPos;
    vec3 m_forceAccumulations;
};

struct Constraint
{
    int particleA;
    int particleB;
    float restLength;
};

class ParticleSystem
{
public:
    ParticleSystem();
    void step(float dt);
    void addConstraint(const Constraint& c);
    void addParticle(const Particle& p);
    void draw(std::function<void(const Particle&)> cb) const;
private:
    void verlet(float dt);
    void satisfyContraints();
    void accumulateForces();


private:
    vec3 m_gravity = {0, 9.81f, 0};
    float m_timestamp = TIMESTAMP;

    std::vector<Particle> m_particles;
    std::vector<Constraint> m_constraints;
};

ParticleSystem::ParticleSystem()
{

}

void ParticleSystem::step(float dt)
{
    accumulateForces();
    verlet(dt);
    satisfyContraints();
}

void ParticleSystem::verlet(float dt)
{
    for (auto& p : m_particles)
    {
        vec3& x = p.m_currentPos;
        vec3 temp_x = x;
        vec3& old_x = p.m_previousPos;
        vec3& a = p.m_forceAccumulations;
        x += (x - old_x) + a * (dt * dt);
        old_x = temp_x;
    }
}

void ParticleSystem::satisfyContraints()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        //satisfy bounds
        for (auto& p : m_particles)
        {
            vec3& v = p.m_currentPos;
            v = glm::min(glm::max(v, { 0,0,0 }), { WIDTH,HEIGHT,HEIGHT });
        }

        // satisfy contsraints
        for (const auto& c : m_constraints)
        {
            vec3& v1 = m_particles[c.particleA].m_currentPos;
            vec3& v2 = m_particles[c.particleB].m_currentPos;
            vec3 delta = v2 - v1;
            float deltaLength = glm::length(delta);
            float diff = (deltaLength - c.restLength) / deltaLength;
            v1 += delta * .5f * diff;
            v2 -= delta * .5f * diff;
        }

        // Constrain one particle of the cloth to orig
        m_particles[0].m_currentPos = { WIDTH / 2 , HEIGHT / 2, 0 };

    }
}

void ParticleSystem::accumulateForces()
{
    for (auto& p : m_particles)
    {
        p.m_forceAccumulations = m_gravity;
    }
}

void ParticleSystem::addConstraint(const Constraint& c)
{
    m_constraints.push_back(c);
}

void ParticleSystem::addParticle(const Particle& p)
{
    m_particles.push_back(p);
}

void ParticleSystem::draw(std::function<void(const Particle& particle)> cb) const
{
    for (const auto& p : m_particles)
    {
        cb(p);
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    ParticleSystem ps;

    vec3 origin = { WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 0 };

    ps.addParticle({ origin, origin, vec3{ 0, 0, 0 } });
    ps.addParticle({ origin + vec3{100,0,0}, origin + vec3{ 100,0,0 }, vec3{ 0, 0, 0 } });

    ps.addConstraint({ 0, 1, 100 });
    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({ WIDTH, HEIGHT }), "Cloth simulation", sf::Style::Close);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();

        // Process events
        for (sf::Event event; window.pollEvent(event);)
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            // Escape key: exit
            if ((event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                window.close();

            // Escape key: exit
            if ((event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A))
                ps.step(1.f);
        }
        // WHEN I UNCOMMENT THIS THIS SIMULATION GOES INSANE
        //ps.step(0.01f);

        ps.draw([&](const Particle& particle) {
            sf::Vertex point[1];
            point[0].position = sf::Vector2f(particle.m_currentPos.x, particle.m_currentPos.y);
            point[0].color = sf::Color::Red;
            window.draw(point, 1, sf::Points);
        });

        // Finally, display the rendered frame on screen
        window.display();
    }
}
```

**------------- Update -------------

following @Lutz Lehmann suggestion it appears the framerate was simply too high what caused a rounding error.
I tried limiting the frame rate and it did the trick.**

Comment: You are hard-coding the time step to a somewhat large value, have you tried decreasing the time step?

Comment: @KyleKanos makes a good suggestion about reducing the timestep. I only skimmed the code, but it also looks like you're enforcing the constraints by clamping some variables. This could be another source of error -- it's worth looking in the [Hairer](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-30666-8) book on methods for constrained Hamiltonian systems, in particular SHAKE and RATTLE. Writing an energy-conserving method for constrained problems is pretty finicky. I wrote a bit about it [here](https://shapero.xyz/posts/surface-billiards/) as well.

Comment: @KyleKanos I tried decreasing the timestamp to about 0.001f but this causes the simulation to not function due to a rounding error..

Comment: It is possible that in the automatic mode the effective frame rate is so high that you see the unavoidable error accumulation much faster than in manual mode. With float numbers the `dt*dt` factor is critical in introducing rounding errors, thus losing accuracy. Switching to velocity or leapfrog Verlet distributes this factor as a simple `dt` factor in position and velocity.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are a life saver! limiting the framerate actually solved the issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LutzLehmann you may want to publish it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

following @Lutz Lehmann suggestion it appears the framerate was simply too high what caused a rounding error. I tried limiting the frame rate and it did the trick.

Comment: Just want to say, this help me immediately ! Thank you !