# Damping not working in Verlet simulation with absolute constraint

Tags: computational-physics, simulation, constraints

I'm trying to build a simple physic simulation with Verlet intergration, which I'm currently implementing as such:

```
tmp                 = currentPosition
currentPosition     = currentPosition * 2 - this->previousPosition + acceleration * timeStep * timeStep
previousPosition    = tmp

acceleration        = Vector2(0, 0)
velocity            = (currentPosition - previousPosition) / timeStep;
```

and everything is updated as such:

1. Add all forces (gravity, damping, ...)
2. Update all points (with the above process)
3. For each substep: Update all constraints

The problem is that damping (described below) doesn't stop the points completely:

```
for each point:
    length = Math::Length(point.velocity);
    force  = Math::normalizeVec(point.velocity) * (-this->dampingCoefficient * length)); 
    point.AddForce(force);
```

after slowing down, at some point it just wobble around uncontrollably: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_m19Jt0QvU)

I have tested all other components, including the constraints (which barely activated at all, and only fixed very miniscule amount ~1e-5). What could be the problem here?

Mind that this setup actually worked great with springs, which use `AddForce()` instead of constraining everything with Constraint(s).

Comment: With damping the system is no longer Hamiltonian and thus symplectic methods do not provide any advantage. You could as well use Euler methods or any other ODE integration method. // Do you apply holonomic forces, or other spring-like forces that work to restore the rigid lengths? Otherwise unconstrained motion inside the step and then restoring the constraints could effectively amount to a force that counteracts the friction. // Note that `Length(A)*normalizeVec(A) = A`, this would save some operations. This friction is the fluid-like kind, air friction is quadratic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried quadratic damping with velocity as well as Velocity Verlet instead of normal Verlet with no success. Seems like too high of a framerate is the problem: [https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42202/issue-in-implementing-a-cloth-simulation-using-verlet-integration?rq=1](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42202/issue-in-implementing-a-cloth-simulation-using-verlet-integration?rq=1). Limiting it to 300fps make everything go up and down nicely.